# How to fill in a form from a Django view?

Tags: django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

Good evening Community,

I am building my first website and I am encountering the following problem. I have a form which has different fields that are to be completed by the user. One of this fields, is the user field which I don't want the user to complete. Hence, I would like to complete from the backend through the views. I tried different things but I am not able to do it, any hints or suggestions?

Hereunder is my code:

Models.py:

```
class CompanyForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Company
    fields = ('company_name', 'outstanding_shares', 'share_price', 'revenue', 'expenses', 'total_assets','total_liabilities', 'current_assets','current_liabilities', 'operating_cashflows', 'capex')
    widgets = {
        'company_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder' : 'Company name'}),
        'outstanding_shares': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder' : 'Shares outstanding'}),
        'share_price':forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder' : 'Share price'}),
        'revenue':forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder' : 'Revenue'}),
        'expenses':forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder' : 'Expenses'}),
        'total_assets':forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder' : 'Total Assets'}),
        'total_liabilities':forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder' : 'Total Liabilities'}),
        'current_assets' :forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder' : 'Current Assets'}),
        'current_liabilities':forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder' : 'Current Liabilities'}),
        'operating_cashflows':forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder' : 'Operating Cashflows'}),
        'capex':forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder' : 'Capital Expenditure'}),            
    }
```

Views.py:

```
def create_comp(request):      
form = CompanyForm()
if request.method == 'POST':
    print(request.POST)
    form = CompanyForm(request.POST)
    user = request.user      
    if form.is_valid(): 
        User = user                                  
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('http://127.0.0.1:8000/companies_list/')
```

When I create the model and check it on the database the user is not assigned.

As per the image below[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have different way to do this

1- for example you can overwrite save method

change code like this:

views.py

```
def create_comp(request):      
    form = CompanyForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.POST)
        form = CompanyForm(request.POST)
        user = request.user      
        if form.is_valid(): 
            form.save(user=user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('http://127.0.0.1:8000/companies_list/')
```

forms.py

```
 class CompanyForm(ModelForm):
      class Meta:
         model = Company
         fields = ('company_name', 'outstanding_shares', 'share_price', 'revenue', 'expenses', 'total_assets','total_liabilities', 'current_assets','current_liabilities', 'operating_cashflows', 'capex')
         widgets = {
        'company_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder' : 'Company name'}),
        'outstanding_shares': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder' : 'Shares outstanding'}),
        'share_price':forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder' : 'Share price'}),
        'revenue':forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder' : 'Revenue'}),
        'expenses':forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder' : 'Expenses'}),
        'total_assets':forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder' : 'Total Assets'}),
        'total_liabilities':forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder' : 'Total Liabilities'}),
        'current_assets' :forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder' : 'Current Assets'}),
        'current_liabilities':forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder' : 'Current Liabilities'}),
        'operating_cashflows':forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder' : 'Operating Cashflows'}),
        'capex':forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder' : 'Capital Expenditure'}),            
         }
      def save(self, **kwargs):
          user = kwargs.pop("user", None)
          instance = super(CompanyForm, self).save(**kwargs)
          instance.user = user
          instance.save()
          return instance
```

2 - you can update Company and add user after form save

views.py

```
def create_comp(request):      
    form = CompanyForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.POST)
        form = CompanyForm(request.POST)
        user = request.user      
        if form.is_valid(): 
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.user = user
            instance.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('http://127.0.0.1:8000/companies_list/')
```